# wifiphisher pyric error

Tags: 20.04, dpkg

When I start using 2wireless adapter it shows this but when I start without external adapter it closes automatically

```
[] Starting Wifiphisher 1.4GIT ( https://wifiphisher.org ) at 2020-08-01 23:01
[+] Timezone detected. Setting channel range to 1-13
[+] Selecting wlxf43e61453d66 interface for the deauthentication attack
[+] Selecting wlp6s0 interface for creating the rogue Access Point
[+] Changing wlp6s0 MAC addr (BSSID) to 00:00:00:17:24:ac
[+] Changing wlp6s0 MAC addr (BSSID) to 00:00:00:ec:68:9d
[+] Sending SIGKILL to wpa_supplicant
[+] Sending SIGKILL to avahi-daemon
[+] Sending SIGKILL to avahi-daemon
[+] Sending SIGKILL to NetworkManager
[] Cleared leases, started DHCP, set up iptables
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyRIC-0.1.6.4-py3.8.egg/pyric/lib/libio.py", line 64, in io_transfer
return ioctl(iosock.fileno(),flag,ifreq)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyRIC-0.1.6.4-py3.8.egg/pyric/pyw.py", line 1962, in flagsset
ret = io.io_transfer(iosock, flag, ifh.ifreq(dev, flag, [flags]))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyRIC-0.1.6.4-py3.8.egg/pyric/lib/libio.py", line 73, in io_transfer
raise error(e.errno,e.strerror)
libio.error: [Errno 5] Input/output error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/wifiphisher", line 11, in
load_entry_point('wifiphisher==1.4', 'console_scripts', 'wifiphisher')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/wifiphisher-1.4-py3.8.egg/wifiphisher/pywifiphisher.py", line 728, in run
engine.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/wifiphisher-1.4-py3.8.egg/wifiphisher/pywifiphisher.py", line 542, in start
self.network_manager.up_interface(mon_iface)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/wifiphisher-1.4-py3.8.egg/wifiphisher/common/interfaces.py", line 476, in up_interface
pyw.up(card)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyRIC-0.1.6.4-py3.8.egg/pyric/pyw.py", line 589, in up
if iosock is None: return iostub(up, card)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyRIC-0.1.6.4-py3.8.egg/pyric/pyw.py", line 2260, in iostub
return fct(*argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyRIC-0.1.6.4-py3.8.egg/pyric/pyw.py", line 594, in up
flagsset(card.dev, setf(flags, ifh.IFF_UP), iosock)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyRIC-0.1.6.4-py3.8.egg/pyric/pyw.py", line 1969, in flagsset
raise pyric.error(e.errno, e.strerror)
pyric.error: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Comment: Sounds like a hacking tool... and as far as I know... we don't support those here.